# Typescript and Graphql Fragments

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client, codegen

I use codegen to generate TS types and I use Apollo client to send queries to server.

when I generate code for the following example, Typescript dosen't know that `people` has `firstName` and `lastName` fields, It only knows that `avatar` field exists. If I remove fragment and move fields directly to query all fields are usable.

What should I do to support fragments correctly?

#### fragments/person.graphql

```
fragment NameParts on Person {
  firstName
  lastName
}
```

#### queries/person.ts

```
import { graphql } from '@/gql'

export const getPersonDocument = graphql(`
   query GetPerson {
     people(id: "7") {
       ...NameParts
       avatar(size: LARGE)
     }
   }
`)
```

`'@/gql'` is the output directory of codegen

Comment: I think the frag should be in a separate file or something from what I'm looking at on Google.

Comment: This is just an example , my fragments are in separate files. I have updated question to clarify that they are not in the same file.